# Unable to identify WinEdit control in CodedUI test

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface

I'm trying to hand-code a simple CodedUI test in VS 2013. I have a simple windows forms app with three TextBoxes (txtA, txtB and txtC) and a Button (btnAdd) on a form. On clicking the button, the app will add the numbers entered in txtA and txtB and show the result in txtC as below:

```
        var a = Convert.ToInt32(txtA.Text);
        var b = Convert.ToInt32(txtB.Text);
        txtC.Text = (a + b).ToString();
```

And my coded UI test is as follows :

```
[TestMethod]
    public void CodedUITestMethod1()
    {
        ApplicationUnderTest app = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"C:\Users\Dileep\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CodedUIDemo\SimpleCalculator\bin\Debug\SimpleCalculator.exe");

        WinEdit txtA = new WinEdit(app);
        WinEdit txtB = new WinEdit(app);
        WinEdit txtC = new WinEdit(app);
        WinButton btnAdd = new WinButton(app);

        txtA.SearchProperties.Add(WinEdit.PropertyNames.Name, "txtA");
        txtB.SearchProperties.Add(WinEdit.PropertyNames.Name, "txtB");
        txtC.SearchProperties.Add(WinEdit.PropertyNames.Name, "txtC");
        btnAdd.SearchProperties.Add(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name, "btnAdd");

        txtA.Text = "50";
        txtB.Text = "50";
        Mouse.Click(btnAdd);
        var result = txtC.GetProperty("Text").ToString();
        Assert.AreEqual("100", result);
    }
```

When I run the test, it launches the app, waits for a while and then fails with the following error :

Result Message:

> Test method SemiAuto.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1 threw exception: 
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Extension.UITestControlNotFoundException: The playback failed to find the control with the given search properties. Additional Details: 
>   TechnologyName:  'MSAA'
>   ControlType:  'Edit'
>   Name:  'txtA'
>    ---> System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException: Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component.
>   Result StackTrace:
>   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.Engine.IScreenElement.FindAllDescendants(String bstrQueryId, Object& pvarResKeys, Int32 cResKeys, Int32 nMaxDepth)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindAllScreenElement(String queryId, Int32 depth, Boolean singleQueryId, Boolean throwException, Boolean resetSkipStep)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITest.Playback.ScreenElement.FindScreenElement(String queryId, Int32 depth, Boolean resetSkipStep)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindFirstDescendant(String queryId, Int32 maxDepth, Int32& timeLeft)
>    --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
>       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapControlNotFoundException(COMException ex, IPlaybackContext context)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowComException(COMException innerException, IPlaybackContext context)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception exception, IPlaybackContext context)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.Playback.MapAndThrowException(Exception exception, String queryId)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindFirstDescendant(String queryId, Int32 maxDepth, Int32& timeLeft)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.GetElement(Boolean useCache, ISearchArgument searchArg)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.SearchHelper.Search(ISearchArgument searchArg)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindInternal()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.FindControlIfNecessary()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.SetPropertyPrivate(String propertyName, Object value)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.<>c__DisplayClass3e.b__3d()
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.CodedUITestMethodInvoker.InvokeMethod[T](Func`1 function, UITestControl control, Boolean firePlaybackErrorEvent, Boolean logAsAction)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.UITestControl.SetProperty(String propertyName, Object value)
>      at Microsoft.VisualStudio.TestTools.UITesting.WinControls.WinEdit.set_Text(String value)
>      at SemiAuto.CodedUITest1.CodedUITestMethod1() in c:\Users\Dileep\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CodedUIDemo\SemiAuto\CodedUITest1.cs:line 41

I tried using the `SetProperty` method but that also doesn't work.

If I run the recorder and generate code, it wraps controls in a WinWindow control. For example, the `txtA` `TextBox` control is wrapped like this in `UIMap` class :

```
 public class UITxtAWindow : WinWindow
{
    public UITxtAWindow(UITestControl searchLimitContainer) : 
            base(searchLimitContainer)
    {
        this.SearchProperties[WinWindow.PropertyNames.ControlName] = "txtA";
        this.WindowTitles.Add("Form1");
    }

    public WinEdit UITxtAEdit
    {
        get
        {
            if ((this.mUITxtAEdit == null))
            {
                this.mUITxtAEdit = new WinEdit(this);
                this.mUITxtAEdit.WindowTitles.Add("Form1");
            }
            return this.mUITxtAEdit;
        }
    }
    private WinEdit mUITxtAEdit;
}
```

I don't understand why it is done like this. Can someone explain this,please ?

Thanks
Dileep Krishnan

Answer (score 0):

You need to add filter properties of the control too. To me you must first use the recorder if you are new and check which properties you are missing. Then you will have better idea how the coded UI search mechanism works.

Comment: When I use the recorder, the same properties are added for these controls as search criteria but each of the controls isl wrapped in a WinWindow control. I don't understand why this required.

Comment: please explain more what you mean by "wrapped in a WinWindow control."

Comment: For example, the txtA TextBox control is represented like this in the UIMap class:

Answer (score 0):

I got the same issue.
To fix it, I have to modify my Application, and set Accessibility properties for the control.

For example:
*Added AcceessibleName = "inpt1"*
and then in test I can search it by

```
control.SearchProperties.Add(WinEdit.PropertyNames.Name, "inpt1");
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this....

```
[TestMethod]
public void CodedUITestMethod1()
{
    ApplicationUnderTest app = ApplicationUnderTest.Launch(@"C:\Users\Dileep\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\CodedUIDemo\SimpleCalculator\bin\Debug\SimpleCalculator.exe");

    WinEdit txtA = new WinEdit(app);
    WinEdit txtB = new WinEdit(app);
    WinEdit txtC = new WinEdit(app);
    WinButton btnAdd = new WinButton(app);

    txtA.SearchProperties.Add(WinEdit.PropertyNames.ControlName, "txtA");
    txtB.SearchProperties.Add(WinEdit.PropertyNames.ControlName, "txtB");
    txtC.SearchProperties.Add(WinEdit.PropertyNames.ControlName, "txtC");
    btnAdd.SearchProperties.Add(WinButton.PropertyNames.Name, "btnAdd");

    txtA.Text = "50";
    txtB.Text = "50";
    Mouse.Click(btnAdd);
    var result = txtC.GetProperty("Text").ToString();
    Assert.AreEqual("100", result);
}
```